# Drawing an arc with pstricks and latex2html5

Tags: javascript, geometry, mathjax

I get an issue about drawing an arc with MathJax and latex2html5 (from http://latex2html5.com/).

I would like to draw this schema with these 2 libraries above :

[image: Schema to repoduce]

My issue is that I can't draw the 2 arcs on the left which link `EV` and `DE` states.

On the link above, I did :

```
<script type="tex/latex">

\begin{center}
\begin{pspicture}(-4,-4)(4,4)

 \pscircle(-3.3,2.5){0.4}
 \pscircle(-3.3,-2.5){0.4}
 \pscircle(3.3,-2.5){0.4}
 \pscircle(3.3,2.5){0.4}

\psline{->}(-2.9,2.5)(2.9,2.5)
\rput(0,2.8){00}

\psline{->}(3.3,2.1)(3.3,-2.1)
\rput(3.6,0){00}

\psline{->}(2.9,-2.5)(-2.9,-2.5)
\rput(0,-2.8){01,11}

\psarc[fillcolor=white]{->}(-3.7,0){2}{-90}{90}

\end{pspicture}
\end{center}

  </script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
  $('body').latex();
  </script>
```

The line :

```
\psarc[fillcolor=white]{->}(-3.7,0){2}{-90}{90}
```

concerns this part but the result is not good: first, fillcolor is blue and after, the interval of angle is not good too (I want the 2 arcs to be vertical).

More generally, I would like to get informations to draw schema (here with different arcs) with latex2html5 library. If this is not possible, does anyone know a Javascript library (ideally with Latex rendering like MathJax or without) that could allow to do this ? Thanks for your suggestions.

Thanks

Comment: I don't know if I am on the suitable forum for this question, it may be redirected to another group on StackOverflow, anyone could do it if necessary ? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

draw an arc you can use psplot, here is a horizontal arc, you can change the axis to make you want.
hope it helps.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
    // <![CDATA[
    MathJax.Hub.Config({ 
        TeX: {extensions: ["AMSmath.js", "AMSsymbols.js"]},     
        extensions: ["tex2jax.js"],
        jax: ["input/TeX", "output/HTML-CSS"],
        showProcessingMessages : false,
        messageStyle : "none" ,    
        showMathMenu: false ,
        tex2jax: {
            processEnvironments: true,
            inlineMath: [ ['$','$'], ["\(","\)"] ],
            displayMath: [ ['$$','$$'], ["\[","\]"] ],
            preview : "none",
            processEscapes: true
        },
        "HTML-CSS": { linebreaks: { automatic:true, width: "latex-container"} }
    });
    // ]]>
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.1/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS_HTML"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Mathapedia/LaTeX2HTML5/master/latex2html5.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Mathapedia/LaTeX2HTML5/master/css/latex2html5.css" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Arbutus+Slab" type="text/css">
</head>
<div id="aa"></div>
<script type="tex/latex">
\begin{center}
\begin{pspicture}(-4,-4)(4,4)
\psplot[algebraic,linewidth=1.5pt]{-3.14}{3.14}{cos(x/2)}
\end{pspicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
  </script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
  $('body').latex();
  </script>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I am going to try with this

Comment: it is working but impossible to add an arrow at the end of arc, I tried to add an arrow with \psplot[algebraic,linewidth=1.5pt,arrows=->]{-3.14}{3.14}{cos(x/2)}

Comment: @youpilat13 yeah I've tried it, and try to find manual about it, but to no avail.  you may add an arrow at the end of the arc.

Comment: @youpilat13 what you do is not is try to plot a reverse function. I mean you have to change axis xy to yx. or rotate 90 degs of the arc. I've very little knowledge about MathJax and latex2html5 and the manual for these two seems poor, so I don't know do the next. Some other tex works very well.

Comment: I have also tried to make a vertical arc by reversing y and x variables, i.e by doing \psplot[algebraic,linewidth=1.5pt,arrows=->]{-1}{1}{2*‌​acos(x)} it seems acos(x) function is not defined, have you got an idea ?

Comment: ok, you are right, documentation for latex2html5 is poor and not all pstrick latex options are available ... I tried to use \rput for 90 degs rotation but it doesn't seem to work

Comment: Note from the future: cdn.mathjax.org is nearing its end-of-life, check https://www.mathjax.org/cdn-shutting-down/ for migration tips.